# How to reference a set of RDF triples in other RDF triples?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, triples

This will be clearer with an example. Assume that the parts have URIs.

Consider a simple statement S1: *Water-Is-Transparent*

Consider another statement S2: *He-Believes-(Water-Is-Transparent)*

How can one write statement S2 as *He-Believes-S1* using RDF? Is there a way in the any knowledge representation (RDF or another) or logic framework that allows making statements such as S2 that derive some parts from previous statements?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_reificationvocab, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312741/simple-example-of-reification-in-rdf?r=SearchResults

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I express additional information (time, probability) about a relation in RDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923213/how-can-i-express-additional-information-time-probability-about-a-relation-in)